# How do you prevent the "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '', with defined functions?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a guess the number game. I have tried to make it so that the user gets 3 guesses, and if the guess is too big, the code says that it is too big and that if the guess is too small, then the code should tell them that, while also allowing them to re-enter their guess, if their answer is out of the range of 1-10, as that is where the number randomly generated comes from. I plan to add other levels and leader boards, so if anyone could help me with this I would appreciate it. Here is my code:

```
import time
import random

answer1= ""
answer2= ""
answer3= ""

one= "You have two more guesses: "
two= "You only have one more guess. Be careful: "

number= random.randint(1,10)
number=str(number)

def code(a,number,b,n,d,e):
    a = int(a)
    number= int(number)
    if a > number and a <11:
        b=input("the number is too big. "+ n )
    elif a< number and a>-1:
        d= input("the number is too big. "+ n )
    elif a> 10 or a<0:
        e=input("please input a number smaller than 10 and bigger than 0: ") 


print(" -------------------- Guess the number game --------------------")
time.sleep(1)
answer= input("The aim of the game is to guess the number. Are you ready? (yes/no): ").lower()

if "yes" in answer:
    answer1=input("I am thinking of a number, between 0 and 10, What is the number: ")

    if answer1 == number:
        print ("Correct! Wow.. it only took you one guess")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Come back again sometime...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("BYE!")
        time.sleep(1)
        quit()


    elif answer1 != number:
        code(answer1,number,answer2,one,answer2,answer2)

    if answer2 == number:
        print ("Correct! it took you two turns.")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Come back again sometime")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("BYE!")
        time.sleep(1)
        quit()


    elif answer2 != number:
        code(answer2,number,answer3,two,answer3,answer3)


    if answer3 == number:
        print ("Correct! Phew.... you guessed correctly in your last guess!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Come back again sometime")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("BYE!")
        time.sleep(1)
        quit()

    elif answer3 != number:
        print("Incorrect..... Sorry! ")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The correct number was "+number)
        time.sleep(1)
        print("You lose! But don't stop trying!")
        time.sleep(1)
        quit()


elif "yes" != answer:
    print("That's too bad...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Come back when you're ready to....")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("LOSE!!")
    time.sleep(1)
    quit()
```

It keeps giving me the: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '', when I use it like so (This is in the shell):

```
 ------------------- Guess the number game --------------------
The aim of the game is to guess the number. Are you ready? (yes/no): yes
I am thinking of a number, between 0 and 10, What is the number: 2
the number is too big. You have two more guesses: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/Guweesss da numba.py", line 63, in <module>
    code(answer2,number,answer3,two,answer3,answer3)
  File "C:/Python33/Guweesss da numba.py", line 19, in code
    a = int(a)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

ignore the weird name of the code- I have tried this multiple times before so did used any name.

Comment: When answer1!= number, it is expected!

Comment: `answer2` is set to `''` at the top and never reassigned.

Comment: you could try `a = int(a) if a else 0` so blank inputs are converted to 0

Comment: You should investigate loops (e.g. `while`, `for`), it would significantly simplify your code.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is python does not pass variables the way you think it does

```
def code(a,number,b,n,d,e):
    a = int(a)
    number= int(number)
    if a > number and a <11:
        b=input("the number is too big. "+ n )
    elif a< number and a>-1:
        d= input("the number is too big. "+ n )
    elif a> 10 or a<0:
        e=input("please input a number smaller than 10 and bigger than 0: ")
```

Whatever you passed as `b`, `d`, and `e` does not get updated when you do `e=input(...)` and therefore `answer2` is still `""` when you're done. There is also no reason to pass the same variable 3 times.

You need to redo this function to return the the result.

```
def code(a,number,n):
    a = int(a)
    number= int(number)
    if a > number and a <11:
        b=input("the number is too big. "+ n )
    elif a< number and a>-1:
        b= input("the number is too big. "+ n )
    elif a> 10 or a<0:
        b=input("please input a number smaller than 10 and bigger than 0: ") 
    return b
```

which is then called via:

```
answer2 = code(answer1, number, one)
```

See the [repl.it](https://repl.it/HjPW/0)

Some further notes:

- You may want to add input error checking, as others have suggested
- You say "the number is too big" for both too large and too small guesses
- You may want to look into a loop so you can keep playing without restarting.
- I would recommend a tutorial on functions and passing variables, as that was the root issue.

Comment: it seems @User9123 asked about something different, didn't he?

Comment: @rth This is the root cause of his issue. He may also want to add error handling for non integer user input, but this will fix is golden path. Adding just integer error handling will **not** fix his program.

Comment: agree, but should we debug the code or answer the question?

Comment: @rth If someone asks an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I tend to think you should answer the actual issue, not the off-base (or in this case an issue that is a symptom of the deeper issue).

Comment: Solving the program so I can reverse engineer it, in essence, will also be helpful should you prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

**ANALYSIS**

You're trying to convert an empty string to an integer.  BOOM!
If you really want such functionality, initialize all three guesses to something like "-1", so the values are syntactically legal, but semantically out of range.

**IMPROVED CHECK**

```
if a.isdigit():
    a = int(a)
else:
    print ("Don't be silly!  I need a number!")
```

**SUGGESTIONS**

Don't write so much code before you test.  Write a few lines, test those, and don't continue until they do what you want.  Here, you're trying to find a small error in 85 lines of code.

Learn how functions work.  Your `code` function accepts six parameters, but ignores `b`, `d`, and `e`, overwriting whatever values came in.  I think that you may have confused those with "mutable" values, things you can change.  The calling program won't receive the assigned values.

Use meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the exception:

```
try:
    a = int(a)
exception ValueError as error:
    print(error)
    print('"{}" is not an integer'.format(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a very pythonical way to check a variables by using `try ... except` construction. So instead a = int(a) something like this:

```
try:
  a = int(a)
except:
  print ... something ...
```

Well, as @TemporalWolf pointed out, there is a big problem with function. So take a look. 
Finally you are trying  to take number and check it, therefore you need a **loop**, probably, until user will give a number from required range. It will look like this

```
a=-1
while 0<a<10:
  answer=input("I am thinking of a number, between 0 and 10, What is the number: ")
  try:
    a = int(answer)
  except:
    print "I need a number!"
    a = -1
    continue
  else:
    if a<1:
      print "number is negative"
      continue
    if a>10:
      print "number too big"
      continue
```

This will guaraty that you input is correct and you have a number from 1 to 10.

NOTE, that @Prune solution is also very nice ( I would use it, honestly :)